# How to create a link between html strings

Tags: c#, ios, html, wkwebview

I have an iOS application where there will be a database of HTML strings which will have links to one another. These HTML strings will be loaded into a `WKWebkitView`.

My question is, how can I create a link for another HTML string in my database from within an HTML string?

```
string html1 = @
"<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta charset=""UTF - 8"">
 </head>            
 <body>
     <a href="""">Link to html2</a>
 </ body >

 </html>";

string html2 = @
"<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta charset=""UTF - 8"">
 </head>            
 <body>
     <a href="""">Link to html1</a>
 </ body >

 </html>";

webView.LoadHtmlString(html1, null);
```